# How to Include Jquery plugin AngularJs Multipage application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a multipage application in AngularJs. My requirement is to open a sublist from a main list in sidebar menu. The sublist collapse out with a transition. I already have a Jquery plugin. It was working perfectly. But when $routeprovider was used in Angular application, it no longer works.

Function for loading jquery is

```
$.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'));
```

The sidebar is common to all pages.

My app.config is as follows

**app.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
     when('/web', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/web.html',
         controller: 'webctrl'
     }).
     when('/login', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
         controller: 'webctrl'
     }).
     when('/register', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
         controller: 'webctrl'
     }).
     when('/account', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
         controller: 'accountctrl'
     }). 
     when('/subtran', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/subtran.html',
         controller: 'subtranctrl'
     }).
     otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/web'
     });
}]);
```

Where do I include the above jquery function

When I included as a script in main html page, it threw a JavaScript runtime Error.

**index.html**

```
<script>
   $.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'));
</script>
```

Help me.

Comment: a JavaRuntime Error.?? are you using java?

Comment: Sorry JavaScript runtime Error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'sidebarMenu'"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I just copied the js scripts from the particular file into  instead of calling it using a function